# Using CheckBoxFor in a form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, checkbox

I have the following form in a view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Subscriptions", "Group", new { id = Model.Id, slug = Model.Slug,  Groups = Model.Groups,  Names = Model.SelectedNames, SelectedMemberEmail = Model.SelectedMember.EmailAddress, WhichView = "Subscriptions", }, FormMethod.Post))
   {
     <div id="communitygroupsedit" class="list-unstyled">
       @for (var x = 0; x < Model.Groups.Count; x++)
          {
             if (Model.Groups[x].Name == "All members")
               {
                  Model.Groups[x].AdminOnly = true;
               }
            string adminTest = (Model.Groups[x].AdminOnly && !Model.IsUserAdministrator) ? "disabled=\"disabled\"" : string.Empty;
            string checktest = Model.Groups[x].IsMember ? "checked=\"checked\"" : string.Empty;

             <p>
               @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Groups[x].IsMember, new { @adminTest @checktest})
               @Html.Raw(Model.Groups[x].Name + " - " + Model.Groups[x].Description)
               @if (adminTest == "disabled=\"disabled\"" && !Model.IsUserAdministrator && checktest == "checked=\"checked\"")
                {
                    Model.SelectedNames.Add(Model.Groups[x].Name);
                }                         
             </p>
      }
       </div>
     if (Model.Groups.Count > 0)
     {
         @Html.SubmitButton("Update groups", false, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" });
      }
```

The problem is that in the controller, the 'Groups' list object is empty and in the view, the checkboxes are not being disabled when the condition is met.  Also the selectednames property is not populating the 'Names' list as I need.  What am I doing wrong in this form?

Comment: IMHO you're doing so much processing in the View, it's hard to understand what's going on. Stuff like adminTest & checktest should really be in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

*What am I doing wrong in this form?* **Everything!**

As for why you not getting `SelectedNames`, your not rendering any controls for it so how would anything post back

If you look at the `action` attribute of the `<form>` tag and it should be obvious. It will have something like

```
<form action="/Group/Subscriptions.....?Names=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BYourAssembly.YourModelName%5D" ....>
```

so when you post the form, the property `SelectedNames` is a string `"System.Collections.Generic.List..."` which cant be bound to a collection.

Now inspect the html for the checkboxes, you will see something like (depending on the values of `adminTest` and `checktest`

```
<input type="checkbox" ... adminTest="" checktest="checked="checked"">
```

which of course does not set the `disabled` or `checked` attributes of a checkbox. Even if your did it correctly and the checkbox was disabled and checked (`true`) it would post back a value of `false` (disabled checkboxes do not post back so the `ModelBinder` would bind to false because of the associated hidden input) and you would get incorrect data.

When you use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Groups[x].IsMember)`, the checkbox state is set based on the value of `IsMember` so the code `string checktest = Model.Groups[x].IsMember ? "checked=\"checked\"" : string.Empty;` is not only wrong, its completely pointless.

And what is the point of `if (Model.Groups.Count > 0)`? The only thing you are editing is `Groups` so if there are none, why would display a blank form which cant be submitted!

Delete all this and create a view model to display/edit what you want

View Model

```
public class GroupVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string DisplayName { get; set; }
  public bool IsMember { get; set; }
}

public class MyModelVM
{
  public int ID {get; set; }
  // any other properties of the model you want to display
  public List<GroupVM> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Group(int ID)
{
  // Get your data model
  ....
  MyModelVM model = new MyModelVM();
  model.Groups = new List<GroupVM>();
  // Populate the collection based on your data model
  foreach(var item in yourDataModel.Groups)
  {
    GroupVM group = new GroupVM();
    // apply you logic here
    if(item.AdminOnly && !item.IsUserAdministrator)
    {
      continue; // no point displaying these
    }
    group.ID = item.ID;
    group.DisplayName = string.Format("{0} - {1}", item.Name, item.Description)
    group.IsMember = item.IsMember;
    model.Groups.Add(group);
  }
  if (model.Groups.Count == 0)
  {
    // ?? is there any point displaying a form?
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model MyModelVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Groups.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Groups[i].ID)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Groups[i].IsMember)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Groups[i].DisplayName)
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Update groups" />
}
```

POST method

```
public ActionResult Group(MyModel model)
{
  // The model contains the ID so get the data model from the database
  // and loop model.Groups to update the data model and save
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for you detailed reply Stephen.  As you may have guessed, programming is a very new thing for me and I often find it very confusing, and have to throw in a lot of guesswork.  I very much look forward to going through your solution in detail.

Answer (score -1):

I'm thrilled to say i finally got it working.  Stephen your post illustrated that I wasn't understanding  how a form is supposed to work as i thought you could just pass any old value from there to the controller.  Your solution unfortunately wouldn't have worked for me, as I still wanted to display the checkbox in a read only state if was an 'adminOnly' checkbox and your code would not have displayed it at all.

I got around the problem of checkboxfor returning false if it was disabled by just rendering a checkbox the way i wanted and then using hiddenfor to return the state of the box.
Another thing you asked is what is the point of if(groups.count> 0) ..show submit button.  It's because if there are no groups, I don't want the submit button being rendered.

I feel I have learned a lot  from this problem, so thanks very much Stephen for all your help.

This is what I came up with:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Subscriptions", "Group", FormMethod.Post))
     {
       <div id="communitygroupsedit" class="list-unstyled">
          <p> @if (Model.Groups[x].AdminOnly)
                {
                  string adminTest = (Model.Groups[x].AdminOnly && !Model.IsUserAdministrator) ? "disabled=\"disabled\"" : string.Empty;
                  string checktest = Model.Groups[x].IsMember ? "checked=\"checked\"" : string.Empty;
                  <input type="checkbox" @adminTest @checktest />

                  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Groups[x].IsMember)
                  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Groups[x].Name)
                  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Groups[x].AdminOnly)
               }
              else
                 {
                   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Groups[x].IsMember)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Groups[x].Name)
                 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Groups[x].AdminOnly)
              }
              @Html.Raw(Model.Groups[x].Name + " - " + Model.Groups[x].Description)
                                             </p>
               }
             </div>
             if (Model.Groups.Count > 0)
           {
           @Html.SubmitButton("Update groups", false, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" });
           }
        }
```

In Controller:

```
 List<string> Names = new List<string>();
 foreach (var group in input.Groups)
   {
     if (group.IsMember)
     Names.Add(group.Name);
   }
```

... write to database

Comment: Your still not getting MVC or Http. There is no such thing as a readonly checkbox - just display "Yes" or "No" (or similar). You should not be rendering hidden inputs for data you don't change. Your opening your self to overposting attacks, and sending a whole lot of data to the client and then back again unchanged just degrades performance - just get it from the database in the POST method if you need to. And as far as `if(groups.count> 0)` - why would you ever return the view in the first place if there were no groups to display, so the `if` is pointless.